# Jquery linking button to specific content

Tags: jquery

I have a concept similar to that of an accordian. I have a button, when clicked, it slides down a div with a specific ID. I have around 3 of these on the page. How do I write one function which automatically chooses the correct div to slide down?

I've seen plugins use `rel` attribute to achieve this. In actual Jquery code, how would I accomplish this?

Eg code:

```
<a rel="#c1">slide 1</a>
<a rel="#c2">slide 2</a>
<div id="c1"></div>
<div id="c2"></div>
```

Comment: do you want to apply to all a elements in the page, if not give a class name to the divs,give same class name and use that in your bindings.

Comment: @gov, na, I'm using a class on those a tags and select it by `$('a.btn').`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var divSelector = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(divSelector).slideDown();
});
```

If you want to get a bit more fancy, you could group your items together (or give them a class) and do something like the following so that the other containers slide up.

```
<div id="sliders">
    <a rel="#c1">slide 1</a>
    <a rel="#c2">slide 2</a>
</div>
<div id="slidees">
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div id="c2"></div>
</div>

$("#sliders a").click(function() {
    var divSelector = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#slidees div").not(divSelector).slideUp();
    $(divSelector).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: @ rfvg , the above code will be applied to all "a" elements rights , he should provide a class name and give that...

Answer (score 0):

Shawn

Use class for divs, so that you can do something like this

```
$('.other').click(function() {

});
```

the above code will be applied to all the elements with same class name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $(target).toggle();
});
```

Comment: @saufiane , the above code may get applied to all "a" elements right , is that what he wants..